# Understanding why this recursive function works

Tags: javascript, recursion

I was not expecting the code below to work but it works perfectly fine. I am expecting `hasValue = hasValue` to overwrite with a false value for `console.log(hasValueDepth(obj, "Elvis Presley"));`. It doesn't do it, so I am missing something.

Can anyone explain to me why this code works?

```js
var obj = {
    "hello": "world",
    "goDeeper": {
        1961: "Barack Obama",
        1964: "Michelle Obama",
        1935: "Elvis Presley",
        1984: {
            "author": "George Orwell",
            "genre": "dystopia",
        }
    }
}

function hasValueDepth(obj, val){
    const values = Object.values(obj);
    let hasValue = values.includes(val)
    
    values.forEach(item => {
        if(typeof item === "object"){
            hasValue = hasValue || hasValueDepth(item, val)
        }
    })
    
    return hasValue;
}

console.log(hasValueDepth(obj, "hello"));
console.log(hasValueDepth(obj, "Elvis Presley"));
console.log(hasValueDepth(obj, "author"));
console.log(hasValueDepth(obj, "dystopia"));
```

Comment: Once your result is `true`, it will _never_ be overwritten, since `||` only moves on to the second value if the first value is `falsy`. The output is as expected, since the value exists and some object has the value, or it doesn't. You could save some cycles by using `Array.find` to stop the loop after it hits `true`, or put an `if` in front of your forEach to check if you haven't found the value already.

Comment: I did ```console.log(hasValue)``` after ```let hasValue = values.includes(val)``` and it displayed ```false``` ```true``` ```true``` for ```console.log(hasValueDepth(obj, "Elvis Presley"));```. Can you explain what is happening at each step? It seems to be taking the last return value as the final value.

Comment: It is not - as soon as the value hits true it can never revert back to any other value, since you are assigning true OR another value, but since true is already truthy, it gets picked. As soon as you have a true, you can return.

Comment: This could be more clearly written without the `||` as `return values.includes(val) || values.filter(e => typeof e === "object").some(e => hasValueDepth(e, val))`. This also has early bailout -- once you found a result, there's no need to keep looking.